# Azure Verizon Premium CDN - Redirect naked domain to www

Tags: azure, cdn

I have an Azure blob with a static website, running a custom domain through Azure CDN. Since I can't get a static IP for the blob, and I can't use alias or A in the DNS records, I'm trying to do a URL redirect through the Azure Verizon CDN Rules Engine.

By looking at other threads on Stack Overflow, I've been able to get a http -> https redirect, but not the naked domain to www redirect.

This is what I have so far (doesn't work). Anyone have some suggestions on how I can fix this - using the rules engine interface?

[Current Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AUn5.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by simply creating a second rule after the https redirect. Make sure both the naked & www domains have been added as custom domains to the CDN.

The rule looks like this:

IF `Edge Cname` `example.com`

Features `URL Redirect` Code `301` Source `[cdn endpoint]` `(.*)` Destination `https://www.example.com/$1`